# how to play games using bumblebee + wine 1.5

Tags: wine, games, bumblebee

I recently moved to ubuntu after seeing "it supports windows games".

Since i have a dual graphics card: Intel 4000 and nvidia 630m, i installed bumblebee to make use of the graphics cards efficiently.

'optirun glxspheres' or any program runs perfect.

Now, the problem is i need to play "NEED FOR SPEED - MOST WANTED (2005)". I have installed wine 1.5.30 and playonlinux. But, i can't play the game.

Also i just tried opening the speed.exe file and game worked fine! Now, my problem is, it uses the intel 4000 graphics. I need to make use of nvidia 630m. Otherwise, spending money on nvidia 630m is a waste right?

So, can you please give me a step-by-step guide to help me sort this problem? 
Thank you :)

Comment: I have similar problem, can't run Civilization V with optirun. It works well without optirun in internal Graphic Card. And optirun works well with glxspheres

Answer (score 1):

cd to the game dir, then try

```
optirun wine speed.exe
```

or

```
optirun bash
wine speed.exe
```